# How physical memory of user and kernel are divided in 64-bit linux system?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

In x86, low memory (from 16MB ~ 896MB) is directly mapped in kernel space and only used by kernel (correct me if wrong). The high memory part is dynamically mapped in kernel space and used by user. In this scenario, generally user will not use low memory and when kernel kmalloc, lowmem is used first.

In x86-64, since we have bigger virtual address space, we can directly map whole physical memory within kernel space and access it directly. Does that mean user and kernel memory mix in physical memory? Or is there a border (like the 896MB line) where the part below it is only used by kernel and user can only allocate memory from the remaining?

Comment: There is no division in physical memory between user and kernel pages.  Why would there be?

Comment: I think the first 1 MB of physical address space is always reserved for the kernel on a x86/x86-64 PC for legacy reasons.

Comment: The "border" you ask about exists for the virtual address space. But the virtual address space is meant to abstract away the underlying physical memory, so that it doesn't matter how physical memory is laid out underneath the hood.

Comment: Also the kernel image is loaded into a contiguous chunk of physical memory somewhere around 16M to make the bootloader's life easier.

Comment: The *low memory (from 16MB ~ 896MB)* you mention is *virtual* address space, not physical like you said in your title.  Anyway, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt for the Linux kernel's layout in virtual address-space; a simple high-half-kernel organization.  IDK what you're asking about physical address space.